# Hiking with children close to Prague, Czechia in winter

Tags: hiking, czech-republic, mountains, prague

We are travelling to Prague, Czechia at the end of December and the forecast is snow. We like light hiking and would like to bring our children to the mountains with snow.

Is there such a place or places around Prague which can be reached in 30-60 minutes by train and offer easy walking and nice views in the winter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Křivoklát Castle and Křivoklátsko Protected Landscape Area* - 1hr by train to Zdice

From there it takes approx 4-5 hrs to reach *Křivoklát Castle* (20km) or you can just take taxi to the castle
[image]

You can also hike to *Jenčov castle ruins or Hrad Točník*. 
[image]

For beautiful nature sceneries visit *Skryje lakes, Nezabudické skály, Týřov, Brdatka and Vuznice*
[image]
also 10km from Zdice there's *Chateau Hořovice and Chateau Zbiroh* within 20 km from Zdice
[image]
[image]
You can either take this route **Zdice - Tocnik - Žebrák castle - Chateau Zbiroh** 
[image]
or **Zdice - Tocnik - Žebrák castle - Skryje lakes - Týřov - Nezabudické skály - Brdatka - Křivoklát - Vuznice - Nižbor chateau - Beroun**
[image]
Or you can just take any other trail and go where you'd like

Comment: We can even take a train up to Krivoklát, so it sounds really good, a really large area, where shorter trips are also possible.

Comment: I didn't know there's a train to Krivoklát but it turns out that you can buy the train ticket at Hlavni Nadrazi (Praha hl.n.) in Prague for Krivoklat, but you have to switch trains at Beroun to a local train to go to Krivoklat. According to tripadvisor, since there are only 2 morning departures from Beroun to Krivoklat, you must catch the train from Prague to Beroun at either 9:12 or 11:42. It is said the whole journey is about 1 1/2 hours total. For the return journey, the train from Krivoklat to Beroun departs almost hourly in the afternoon at 14:06, 15:20, 16:11, 17:10, 18:58, and 20:54.

Comment: Don’t worry about the trains, I even can go to the end of the world with trains :)))) we already have our tickets to there

Answer (score 3):

A snow is a scarcity these years in Czechia. The most of snow is usually in Krkonose, Jizerske mountains, Jeseniky and Šumava. The trouble is that Prague is not within of one hour train ride of any significant mountains by train.

If you have more time, then you can visit Hrensko - wonderful place where Narnia movie was shot. This place is called Czech Switzerland. You will find beautiful rocks, arcs ..
http://jetrichovicko.euweb.cz/indexen.htm

[image]

If you take a bus at Cerny most subway station there are connections to Jizerske hory that are slightly over one hour ride.

Comment: I see, all of those mountains are far from Prague, sometimes close to the borders.

Comment: Yes, se are surrounded by mountains like Mordor! :-)